# Can someone please give me reference about how to make mobile into silent mode on reaching specific location .?

Tags: android, location, silent

I want to make mobile silent when the user reached to the user saved location. Please suggest me some ideas and relevant reference links to make it done.

Comment: What did you try. We are not a free code service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by **Creating and Monitoring Geofences**. You can get a reference here https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Comment: how can i compare the the saved values in sqlite database with the broadcast receiver class latitude and longitude

Comment: you can't do it just by comparing the latitude and longitude. You need to create a boundary radius for your lat lng. Once you entered the geo area your intent service is called. You can make your phone configuration changes there. once you set the lat lng to geofence object you don't need to save it to your SQLite database. google play service will take care the rest.